Runtime Error - Set olRule = olRules.Item(i) after Microsoft update, where rules setup as 'Through the Specified Account'
ERROR: 2020.05.26 - Since last Microsoft update, code fails on rules setup as 'Through the Specified Account'.
When it hits
Set olRule = olRules.Item(i)

it throws:

Run-time error '-2146664191 [800c8101]

Private Function FindRule(strRuleName As String) As Boolean
     'error handler
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    'default process boolean to failed
    FindRule = False
         
    'open rules object
    Set olRules = Outlook.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

    'loop through rules to see if the rule is in the rules list    
    If olRules.Count = 0 Then
    'no rules, so it can't exist
        FindRule = False
    Else
    'check the list of rules
        'For i = olRules.Count To 1 Step -1
        For i = 1 To olRules.Count
            Set olRule = olRules.Item(i)
            If olRule.Name = strRuleName Then
                FindRule = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    'rule not found. let folks know
    If FindRule = False Then
        Err.Raise 60001, "Rule Error", "Rule not found!"
    End If
    
ExitFunction:
    'skip error handler
    Exit Function
    
ErrorHandler:
    'display error
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "FindRule - Error: " & CStr(Err.Source)
    'clear error
    Err.Clear
    'return failed boolean
    FindRule = False

End Function

OnError Resume Next does not allow the execution to continue.
Deleting the rule 'Through the Specified Account' allows the code to execute.

SOLVED!
I found the answer at https://community.spiceworks.com/t/getting-runtime-error-2147467229-80004023-in-excel-vba-macro/743482
The solution was to delete the registry key: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

The error is E_ACCT_NOT_FOUND, which means the account referenced by the rule no longer exists. Edit the rule and point it to the right
account.

The account is valid and receives email without an issue. I am thinking it has less to do with the account and more to do with the 'on this computer only' part of the rule. It cannot be unchecked, and automatically checks when the 'from a specified account' is checked.

I think you are missing my point - accounts are referenced by rules by the account id. If the account was deleted and then recreated, the account id will be different (even if the account has the same name and all other properties). Try to edit that rule and reset the account it references.

Thanks for the follow-up information. There are three accounts for this person. I have tried each of the accounts and get the same 'Automation error'. I also tried one of the accounts I have and the code fails in the same place.

I have deleted the two rules for 'specified account' and the code runs. I re-created a new 'specified account' rule with a different account and the error returns. I am not sure how to 'reset the account it references'. Do I need to try and repair the rules somehow? Like delete and re-create the rules? I have code to do that for all except the 'specified account' rules.
